# display error message in jsp with javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a jsp file contains a form and I need to validate the form. The jsp page will be opened as pop-up page and hence I choose not to pop-up the validation message again. Here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function validateForm() {
        var x=document.forms["myForm"]["name1"].value;
        if (x.trim().length<=4){
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

```html
<form name="myForm" method="POST" action="write.jsp" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name1" value="<%=name%>" size="20"/>  <br> 
    Price: <input type="text" name="price"  value="<%=price%>" size="20" /><br> 
    Due time: <input type="text" name="DueTime"  value="<%=dueday%>" size="20" /><br> 
    Location: <input type="text" name="Location"  value="<%=address%>" size="20" /><br> 
    Photo Url: <input type="text" name="url"  value="<%=imagePath%>" size="20" /><br> 
    Description: <input type="text" name="desc"  value="<%=desc%>" size="20" /><br> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="window.close()"/>
    <% if(validateForm = false) { %> <a>error message</a> <% } %>
</form>
```

I am validating for first input `"name1"` only and the input length is less than 4.
I'd like to display a error message below the submit button. The codes is not working, can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: Why don't you use [HTML input maxlength attr](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp)?

Comment: @Palvo he wants greater then 4. maxlength doesn't help OP

Comment: I do have error on this line  <% if(validateForm = false) { %> <a>error message</a> <% } %> how should I write the jsp tgt with html to display message?  @LOL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 document.getElementsByName('name1')[0].value;
```

in place of

```
document.forms["myForm"]["name1"].value;
```

---

use a span below the submit button
html

```
<span id="error"></span>
```

script

```
function validateForm()
                {
                var x=document.getElementsByName('name1')[0].value;
                if (x.trim().length<=4)
                  {
                    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML="atleast 4 letters required in name";
                    return false;
                  }
                }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I figured out why it keeps closing. Because I added onclick="window.close()" for the submit button. Hmm, now it displays the error message. But since it is a pop-up window, is there any way to auto-close it if all the inputs are valid?

Comment: I think I did it, Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementsByName("name1")` instead of `document.forms["myForm"]["name1"].value;`

Use as

```
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.getElementsByName("name1").value;
if (x.trim().length<=4)
  {
    alert("Message");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: why `document.forms["myForm"]["name1"].value;` doesn't  work?

Comment: @LOL `getElementsByName()` returns an array , so it should be accessed using an index

Comment: Hmm, I didn't downvote this answer, but I modified my code accordingly, there is still no error message displayed..Any idea on that?

Comment: @user1805430 - <input type="button" name="submit" onclick="return window.close();"/>

Comment: @AmitAgrawal Thanks for your solution! but it still closed without showing the error message when the input is less than 4..